# Div height not being resized after element is shown

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a page powered by angularjs, which performs a function.
Based on this function, a div that is hidden by default is populated and then shown to the user.

The problem is that when this text is shown, the main div that contains my page content does not seem to be resizing, and as such while the footer moves down just fine, it leaves a massive ugly whitespace, as seen below.

Before function:
[image]

After function:[image]

How do I ensure the main page content div resizes to accommodate this new content?

CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
}

#body{
    background-color: #EAFFE5;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px; 
    font-family: Calibri;  
}

.content{    
    width:85%;
    border: 0px solid #000;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    clear: both;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 700px;   

}

.content a:link,
.content a:visited{
    color:blue;
}

.display{
    width: 90%;
    border: 0px solid #000;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    clear:both;
    text-align: justify;    
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="body" ng-controller="recipeSubmitController">
        <div class="content">
            <title>Submit a recipe</title>
            <h3>Recipe Submission</h3>
            <div class='display'>
                <form name="recipeSubmitForm">
                    <p>Recipe Title: *</p>
                    <input type ='text' maxlength="200" id="titleInput" class="forminput" ng-model="titleInput"style="float:left;" placeholder="Paste or write recipe title here." required>

                    <br>
                    <br>

                    <p>Ingredients: *</p>
                    <textarea rows="5" maxlength="3600" class='formtextarea' ng-model="ingredientsInput" placeholder="Paste or write recipe ingredients here." required></textarea>
                    <br>
                    <br>

                    <p>Instructions: *</p>
                    <textarea rows="5" maxlength="3600" class='formtextarea' ng-model="instructionsInput" placeholder="Paste or write recipe instructions here." required></textarea>
                    <br>
                    <br>

                    <button id="basicRecipeSubmitButton" class="buttonstyled" style="float:right;" ng-click='basicRecipeSubmitClicked()'>Submit data</button>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                </form>

                <br>
                <br>                
                <div id="recipeMainBody" ng-show="parsedDataShown" ng-cloak="true">
                    <h4>Here's a sneak peek of how the recipe will look:</h4>
                    <br>
                    <h4><span  ng-bind="recipeObject.title"></span></h4>
                    <div id="recipeSideInfo" style="float:left; width:20%; text-align: left;">
                        <h4>Ingredients:</h4>
                        <li ng-repeat="ingredients in recipeObject.ingredients | orderBy:'-Amount'">
                            {{ ingredients.Amount + ' ' + ingredients.Units + ' '+ ingredients.Name}}
                        </li>

                    </div>
                    <div id="recipeInstructions" style="float:right; width:75%">
                        <h4>Instructions:</h4>
                        <li ng-repeat="instruction in recipeObject.instructions | orderBy: 'Step'" style="list-style-type: none;">
                            {{ instruction.Step + '. ' + instruction.Text }}
                        </li>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#recipeInstructions` is floated, so you need to clear it's parent.

You can create a `.clearfix` class and apply that to parents with floated children, or you can just apply this `.clearfix` CSS to `#recipeMainBody`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

#body{
    background-color: #EAFFE5;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px; 
    font-family: Calibri;  
}

.content{    
    width:85%;
    border: 0px solid #000;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    clear: both;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 700px;   

}

.content a:link,
.content a:visited{
    color:blue;
}

.display{
    width: 90%;
    border: 0px solid #000;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    clear:both;
    text-align: justify;    
}

.clearfix:after {
    display: table;
    content: '';
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="body" ng-controller="recipeSubmitController">
  <div class="content">
    <title>Submit a recipe</title>
    <h3>Recipe Submission</h3>
    <div class='display'>
      <form name="recipeSubmitForm">
        <p>Recipe Title: *</p>
        <input type='text' maxlength="200" id="titleInput" class="forminput" ng-model="titleInput" style="float:left;" placeholder="Paste or write recipe title here." required>

        <br>
        <br>

        <p>Ingredients: *</p>
        <textarea rows="5" maxlength="3600" class='formtextarea' ng-model="ingredientsInput" placeholder="Paste or write recipe ingredients here." required></textarea>
        <br>
        <br>

        <p>Instructions: *</p>
        <textarea rows="5" maxlength="3600" class='formtextarea' ng-model="instructionsInput" placeholder="Paste or write recipe instructions here." required></textarea>
        <br>
        <br>

        <button id="basicRecipeSubmitButton" class="buttonstyled" style="float:right;" ng-click='basicRecipeSubmitClicked()'>Submit data</button>
        <br>
        <br>
      </form>

      <br>
      <br>
      <div id="recipeMainBody" class="clearfix" ng-show="parsedDataShown" ng-cloak="true">
        <h4>Here's a sneak peek of how the recipe will look:</h4>
        <br>
        <h4><span  ng-bind="recipeObject.title"></span></h4>
        <div id="recipeSideInfo" style="float:left; width:20%; text-align: left;">
          <h4>Ingredients:</h4>
          <li ng-repeat="ingredients in recipeObject.ingredients | orderBy:'-Amount'">
            {{ ingredients.Amount + ' ' + ingredients.Units + ' '+ ingredients.Name}}
          </li>

        </div>
        <div id="recipeInstructions" style="float:right; width:75%">
          <h4>Instructions:</h4>
          <li ng-repeat="instruction in recipeObject.instructions | orderBy: 'Step'" style="list-style-type: none;">
            {{ instruction.Step + '. ' + instruction.Text }}
          </li>
          <li ng-repeat="instruction in recipeObject.instructions | orderBy: 'Step'" style="list-style-type: none;">
            {{ instruction.Step + '. ' + instruction.Text }}
          </li>
          <li ng-repeat="instruction in recipeObject.instructions | orderBy: 'Step'" style="list-style-type: none;">
            {{ instruction.Step + '. ' + instruction.Text }}
          </li>
          <li ng-repeat="instruction in recipeObject.instructions | orderBy: 'Step'" style="list-style-type: none;">
            {{ instruction.Step + '. ' + instruction.Text }}
          </li>
          <li ng-repeat="instruction in recipeObject.instructions | orderBy: 'Step'" style="list-style-type: none;">
            {{ instruction.Step + '. ' + instruction.Text }}
          </li>
          <li ng-repeat="instruction in recipeObject.instructions | orderBy: 'Step'" style="list-style-type: none;">
            {{ instruction.Step + '. ' + instruction.Text }}
          </li>
          <li ng-repeat="instruction in recipeObject.instructions | orderBy: 'Step'" style="list-style-type: none;">
            {{ instruction.Step + '. ' + instruction.Text }}
          </li>
          <li ng-repeat="instruction in recipeObject.instructions | orderBy: 'Step'" style="list-style-type: none;">
            {{ instruction.Step + '. ' + instruction.Text }}
          </li>
          <li ng-repeat="instruction in recipeObject.instructions | orderBy: 'Step'" style="list-style-type: none;">
            {{ instruction.Step + '. ' + instruction.Text }}
          </li>
          <li ng-repeat="instruction in recipeObject.instructions | orderBy: 'Step'" style="list-style-type: none;">
            {{ instruction.Step + '. ' + instruction.Text }}
          </li>
          <li ng-repeat="instruction in recipeObject.instructions | orderBy: 'Step'" style="list-style-type: none;">
            {{ instruction.Step + '. ' + instruction.Text }}
          </li>
          <li ng-repeat="instruction in recipeObject.instructions | orderBy: 'Step'" style="list-style-type: none;">
            {{ instruction.Step + '. ' + instruction.Text }}
          </li>
          <li ng-repeat="instruction in recipeObject.instructions | orderBy: 'Step'" style="list-style-type: none;">
            {{ instruction.Step + '. ' + instruction.Text }}
          </li>
          <li ng-repeat="instruction in recipeObject.instructions | orderBy: 'Step'" style="list-style-type: none;">
            {{ instruction.Step + '. ' + instruction.Text }}
          </li>
          <li ng-repeat="instruction in recipeObject.instructions | orderBy: 'Step'" style="list-style-type: none;">
            {{ instruction.Step + '. ' + instruction.Text }}
          </li>
          <li ng-repeat="instruction in recipeObject.instructions | orderBy: 'Step'" style="list-style-type: none;">
            {{ instruction.Step + '. ' + instruction.Text }}
          </li>
          <li ng-repeat="instruction in recipeObject.instructions | orderBy: 'Step'" style="list-style-type: none;">
            {{ instruction.Step + '. ' + instruction.Text }}
          </li>
          <li ng-repeat="instruction in recipeObject.instructions | orderBy: 'Step'" style="list-style-type: none;">
            {{ instruction.Step + '. ' + instruction.Text }}
          </li>
          <li ng-repeat="instruction in recipeObject.instructions | orderBy: 'Step'" style="list-style-type: none;">
            {{ instruction.Step + '. ' + instruction.Text }}
          </li>
          <li ng-repeat="instruction in recipeObject.instructions | orderBy: 'Step'" style="list-style-type: none;">
            {{ instruction.Step + '. ' + instruction.Text }}
          </li>
          <li ng-repeat="instruction in recipeObject.instructions | orderBy: 'Step'" style="list-style-type: none;">
            {{ instruction.Step + '. ' + instruction.Text }}
          </li>
          <li ng-repeat="instruction in recipeObject.instructions | orderBy: 'Step'" style="list-style-type: none;">
            {{ instruction.Step + '. ' + instruction.Text }}
          </li>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
```